# Make all TabBarItems initially unselected

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

In `TabBar` first `TabBarItem` is default selected.
 But is there any possibility to keep `unselected` all tab initially?

You can see the below image first `TabItem` is default selected

[Tab Bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEr37.png)

Comment: One tab must be selected by default or nothing would show. there must be a view controller selected/set

Comment: okay.
so i have to create custom tabbar only?

Comment: yeah, or adjust the appearance of a selected tab so that it appears to be not selected

Answer (score 0):

We cant turn off the tabbar selection, so I think you can just change the
color to make it look like nothing was selected.

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.gray()
```

---

When you want selection, make sure that you have valid tint color and then change tintcolor again.

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = self.view.tintColor;
```